# Why is the .push() method repeating values of the very last element it adds to an array?

Tags: javascript

```
const maxObj = [{"BTCH#BD":57887,"BTYPEBD":"OCO"},
                {"BTCH#BD":57887,"BTYPEBD":"OCO"},
                {"BTCH#BD":57890,"BTYPEBD":"OTH"}]
const req = "4976809";


const result = [];
const temp = { reqId: req, batch: null };

for (var x = 0; x < maxObj.length; x++) {
    temp.batch = maxObj[x];

    result.push(temp);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

In this code I'm trying to iterate through an an array of objects and assigning each object to the property of a temporary template object that I then push to the results array. My expected output is something like this:

```
[{"reqId":"4976809","batch":{"BTCH#BD":57887,"BTYPEBD":"OCO"}},
 {"reqId":"4976809","batch":{"BTCH#BD":57887,"BTYPEBD":"OCO"}},
 {"reqId":"4976809","batch":{"BTCH#BD":57890,"BTYPEBD":"OTH"}}]
```

But my actual output is like this:

```
[{"reqId":"4976809","batch":{"BTCH#BD":57890,"BTYPEBD":"OTH"}}, 
 {"reqId":"4976809","batch":{"BTCH#BD":57890,"BTYPEBD":"OTH"}}, 
 {"reqId":"4976809","batch":{"BTCH#BD":57890,"BTYPEBD":"OTH"}}]
```

How do I fix this so I get the expected output above?

Comment: You need to build a completely new `temp` object on each iteration through the loop.

Comment: Because you keep pushing the same object.

Comment: you need to dig into what a "reference" is. and why overriding temp.batch is not doing what you expect.

Comment: But I thought temp.batch = maxObj[x]; overwrites the previous temp object on each for loop iteration? I know it's the same object but my reasoning was that the object would get updated with new values each time.

Comment: *"overwrites the previous temp object"* No, it just changes the value of a property. But all references to that object `temp` are still pointing to the very same *(now updated)* object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the same object for pushing. You get same objects inside of the array.

You could use a new object with wanted property to prevent to store the same object reference.

```js
const maxObj = [{"BTCH#BD":57887,"BTYPEBD":"OCO"},
            {"BTCH#BD":57887,"BTYPEBD":"OCO"},
            {"BTCH#BD":57890,"BTYPEBD":"OTH"}]
const req = "4976809";
const result = [];

for (var x = 0; x < maxObj.length; x++) {
    result.push({ reqId: req, batch: maxObj[x] });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```